# Generic run configurations in intellij and path to active module

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I'm transitioning from eclipse to intellij and like some (http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/452846), I'd like to have a variable comparable to eclipse's ${project_loc}. Seeing some of the responses out there I learned that I can use environment variables, but this isn't quite what I want.

I'd really like intellij to be able to determine which module has focus, then run using that module's base directory as the runtime path. I have a group of modules that I want to run the same run configuration on at different times. I don't want to have to define separate run configurations for each individual module.

This is how I did it in eclipse, so I'm inclined to want to do it the same way. If perhaps there's a different way to accomplish the same goal, I'm all for it. Here's our use case:

We have a number of jars that each include javascript files. As part of the build process these javascript files are pulled out of the jar and aggregated together in an all.js file. During development we want to be able to update this all.js file on the fly while the server is running. Due to the aggregation step we can't use built-in hotswapping-like functionality to update client resources. For this we have created a run configuration, that when run will aggregate the js and copy it onto the local app server.

This run configuration for eclipse is currently used to do this for multiple projects and is also shared between many developers. Again, the main desire is a generic variable that is agnostic to both the project/module as well as the base path to that module.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The first thing that come to my mind is starting your build process as an _external tool_ (configured in "Settings">"External Tools"). Have the tool _show in Project views_ and use `$FileDir$` as an argument or working directory. Now you should be able to right-click a module/project/directory and start your process. Don't know if that helps.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. So.... why not add it as an answer in the first place? Please add it as an answer so I can mark it as such. And bonus points for adding how I can chain the external tools together, so that more than one is triggered after the first tool has completed :).

Comment: I spoke too soon. This is *almost* what I was looking for. Is there a way I have it resolve other modules from the workspace, like I can in the run configurations?